# Integrating StumbleUpon badge with GA Social Engagement

Tags: google-analytics, stumbleupon

Trying to enable GA tracking with some social sharing buttons...

We have the following:
- Facebook
- Twitter
- LinkedIn
- Stumble Upon

I have all working except Stumble Upon!! Basically, I just need to bind into an event that someone has completed their interaction. Their documentation is horrible.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

**short answer:** I do not believe this is possible.

**long answer:** I've combed through their docs and many sites trying to do the same thing to no avail.  Some services like AddThis are tracking it in some form or fashion but there is nothing that would lead me to believe they are doing so in a non-hack way.  It might be possible work through their STMBLPN.Widget javascript in firebug or some developer tool to reverse engineer a solution.  I tried but was unsuccessful.  Even if you are though, since its not officially supported your code will break if they decide to change what you are relying on.